# Turn off Wi-Fi via C# on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

Is there a way to turn off Wi-Fi on Windows 10 via C# as if I pressed that button in Internet access menu (or Action Center) as in the link below?

[Wi-Fi buttton, Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lRyp.png)

Forgot to say. I am writing a WPF application. Will these methods work on it? I've tried them, but it seems like I don't have a reference for some library.

Comment: Try with this API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.radios.aspx.

Comment: I thing Eugene's question is about wpf, not uwp.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to request access to be able to modify the radio with **WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync()**, furthermore you get the radios with **Radio.GetRadiosAsync()** and check the one with **Kind** as **WiFi**, finally you disable it with **SetStateAsync(RadioState.Off)**.

```
var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
if (access == WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
     var radios = await Radio.GetRadiosAsync();
     foreach (var radio in radios)
     {
          if (radio.Kind == RadioKind.WiFi)
          {
              await radio.SetStateAsync(RadioState.Off);
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: The class doesn't exist in WPF, so probably not, I've looked for one for desktop / classic applications.